# Task using full probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

I'm trying to solve this problem for a long time. Unfortunately I can't make it out((

On the floor are boxes in each of which are m pairs of red socks and n black ones. Peter pulls a random sock out of the first box and shifts next random sock into the second, then pulls the sock out of the second box and puts it in the third box, etc. Find the probability that a red sock will be pulled out of the k box

I tried:

Denote Ri - pulled red from i-that box; Bi - pulled black from i-that box
$$P(R1)=m/(n+m); P(B1)=n/(n+m);$$
$$P(R2/R1)=(m+1)/(n+m+1); P(R2/B1)=m/(n+m+1)$$
$$P(B2/R1)=n/(n+m+1); P(B2/B1)=(n+1)/(n+m+1)$$

$$P(R3/R2/R1)=(m+2)/(n+m+2); P(R3/R2/B1)=(m+1)/(n+m+2)$$
$$P(R3/B2/R1)=(m+1)/(n+m+2); P(R3/B2/B1)=m/(n+m+2)$$

$$P(B3/R2/R1)=n/(n+m+2); P(B3/R2/B1)=(n+1)/(n+m+2)$$
$$P(B3/B2/R1)=(n+1)/(n+m+2); P(B3/B2/B1)=(n+2)/(n+m+2)$$
And so on so forth, that I hope you can help me. Thanks for attention!

Comment: What does your $x/y/z$ notation mean?

Comment: Did you mean that Peter pulls the a sock out the second box and puts it in the third? Otherwise, it sounds like Peter transfers the same sock from the first box to the second box and then to the third box.

Comment: To type $\Pr(F \mid E)$, type `$\Pr(F \mid E)$`.

Comment: N. F. Taussig, right, good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability of selecting a red sock from the $k$th box is just
$$\frac{m}{m + n}$$
since you are equally likely to choose any of the $2(m + n)k$ socks in the first $k$ boxes and $2mk$ of these socks are red.  Observe that
$$\frac{2mk}{2(m + n)k} = \frac{m}{m + n}$$

Clearly, this is true for $k = 1$.

Let's overthink the $k = 2$ case.

Let $Pr(R)$ be the probability of selecting a red sock from the first box.

Let $P(B)$ be the probability of selecting a black sock from the first box.

Let $Pr(R \mid R)$ be the probability of selecting a red sock from the second box given that a red sock has been selected from the first box.

Let $\Pr(R \mid B)$ be the probability of selecting a red sock from the second box given that a black sock has been selected from the first box.

Then the probability of selecting a red sock from the second box is 
\begin{align*}
\Pr(R)\Pr(R \mid R) + \Pr(B)\Pr(R \mid B) & = \frac{2m}{2(m + n)} \cdot \frac{2m + 1}{2(m + n) + 1} + \frac{2n}{2(m + n)} \cdot \frac{2m}{2(m + n) + 1}\\
& = \frac{m}{m + n} \cdot \frac{2m + 1}{2m + 2n + 1} + \frac{n}{m + n} \cdot \frac{2m}{2m + 2n + 1}\\
& = \frac{m(2m + 2n + 1)}{(m + n)(2m + 2n + 1)}\\
& = \frac{m}{m + n}
\end{align*}

For an induction proof, we already have the $k = 1$ and $k = 2$ cases.  Assume that the result holds when $k = \ell$.  Finish the argument by adapting the argument given for the $k = 2$ case to show that the results holds for $k = \ell + 1$. Conclude that it holds for each positive integer value of $k$.

More simply, read the argument in the first paragraph.

Comment: I understood, thank You very much:)

Comment: Note that there are $m$ **pairs** of red socks in each box, not $m$ red **socks** in each box.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Thanks for pointing out the error.